Powerapps - Dataverse View not filtered correctly
We have a Power App with a Dropdown that is supposed to show items from a filtered Dataverse list. It's filtered by a status column - active/inactive. We have the same app in a Development and Production environment and import from one to the other as an unmanaged solution.
Until recently, this worked perfectly fine. In the Dev environment, it's still working but in Prod, the dropdown contains all active and inactive items. The Dataverse table contains less than 100 entries, so surely it can't be a limitation issue.
We have also manually refreshed the data source directly in both dev and prod apps but no luck.
Has anyone experienced something like this before?
Thanks,
Jenny

Can you please share what you are using to filter the records, bcz I can't figure out whats worng.

On the Items property on the dropdown (the DataCardValue of the DataCard), there's this formula: Filter('LIST NAME','LIST NAME (Views)'.'Active Items')
